# can someone tell me what this angle is or if its a typo in the image

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Can someone tell me what this angle is, or if its a typo in the image?

[image]

It's $2^\circ24'$

I don't need help with the question. Just trying to understand what the angle is supposed to be.

Comment: It's 2 degrees and 24 [minutes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc) i.e., $\left(2+\frac{24}{60}\right)^\circ$

Comment: It's $\left(\frac{2}{180} + \frac{24}{180\cdot 60}\right)\pi$ radians i.e., $\frac\pi{75}$ rads.